# How to handle URL encoded parameter separators when responding to AJAX crawled _escaped_fragment?

Tags: seo, googlebot, ajax

I've been reading about how to handle Google requested URL [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification)

There is an example from Google :

- Pretty URL: `www.example.com?myquery#!key1=value1&key2=value2`
- Ugly URL: `www.example.com?myquery&_escaped_fragment_=key1=value1%26key2=value2`

As you can see, in the ugly URL there is  "%26" characters, as explained by Google that they need to be unescaped by the web server to obtain the original URL:

```
%00..20
%23
%25..26
%2B
%7F..FF
```

As in the example, the "%26" (ugly URL) represents the "&" (pretty URL), 
so in this case, we need to replace "%26" with "&" to get the original URL.

How do we know which character is represented by the special characters that Google replaced?

Answer (score 1):

This may be an old question but for the purposes of providing it an up to date answer, this is no longer required. Google no longer needs, and in fact encourages users not, to use escape fragments for the URL's as the Googlebot is now able to understand javascript generated page content without needing a URL escape fragment. This can be seen in the depreciation notice at https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html